# Where are MIBs installed?

Tags: snmp

I'm a little confused on where MIBs are installed/required for SNMP.  Do they need to be on both the end point device AND the monitoring tool?  Or just the monitoring tool?

Comment: See this [discussion](https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/653-how-do-snmp-mibs-and-oids-work). Also Google [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=SNMP+MIBs) has many results.

Answer (score 1):

By monitoring tool, I assume you mean the SNMP manager that receives traps/polls devices for their status.

In that case, the MIB (management information base) only needs to be installed on the manager. It uses the MIB to translate numeric OIDs in the SNMP messages, for example `1 . 3 . 6 . 1 . 4 . 1 . 3 . 1 . 4 . 5 . 1 . 1. 99 . 1 . 1 . 6`, into something human readable like `alarm condition`.